# Supabase session cookie doesn't persist when I close my browser (Nextjs)

Tags: cookies, next.js, supabase

I have a Nextjs app which uses supabase magic link auth and I check authentication by retrieving the session cookie that was stored once the user signed up

```js
const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies });
    const {
        data: { user },
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

if(user){
return (<>Page</>)
}
```

Now its come to my attention that these cookies do not persist beyond the session and I guess the session ends once the browser is closed. So, how do I edit the cookie or change the type of expiry to be indefinite rather than on a session?

Surely I can do something like this instead of having to do something with localStorage.

Comment: Supabase uses JWTs when dealing with sessions, this is something you don't want to be long lived as there isn't a way to revoke a single JWTs once it has been issued.